# dired by name - change directory and create new file

Tags: dired, find-file

I want to open a new file in a different directory than the current one.

Pressing `C-x C-f` -> I could enter a file name. But I don't.

Pressing `RET`

The directory listing (mode `(dired by name)`) comes up and I can navigate through it by using the cursor and `RET`. No problem.

I navigate to the existing directory I want to create the new file in.

How can I enter the name of the new (nonexisting) file in that case?

*EDIT*: Because I am quite new to *emacs*: [How could I answer such simple questions to my self](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/61326/12999)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer based on [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20300137/4865723).

Press `C-x C-f` and you are back to the minibuffer and can enter a filename.